# using multi choice and collection in blueprism

Tags: collections, blueprism

I have about 3 collections and i want to write into an excel and send them in mail separately, I tried to use multi choice to finalize one after the other but it doesn't work
any other idea how to do this?
I will put screen shots below for more illustration

[image: process over view]

[image: choice over view]

Comment: You need to add more details to your question - "it's not working" is not a problem statement. Edit your question to add expected vs. actual behavior, along with any error messages Blue Prism is throwing you. Please also edit your question to conform to the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guidelines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's likely not functioning the way you intended because each of the three Data Items you're attempting to compare to a blank string (`""`) aren't Text-typed - rather, they're Collections. Collections themselves can't be compared to strings (see: apples and oranges), but the data contained *within* them can.

What you're likely attempting to do is to compare the value within the current row of each of those collections - it's not clear what the field name is from your screenshot (the field name itself is cut off on the right edge) but your comparisons should look something like the following:

```
[No Amount.Politic]<>""
```

```
[Pending difference.Field]<>""
```

```
[Ready to print.Field]<>""
```